# Gunicorn crush on GC AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

Today I tried to deploy Python application on Google Cloud AppEngine. This version was successfully deployed before, but now it crashes with a strange reason.
Request on /_ah/start returns 502 error with message:

```
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

and then after a few seconds
500 status code with the next message:

```
The request failed because the instance could not start successfully
```

Error reporting shows one exception for this app:

```
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, 
in handle_chld
at sleep (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:360)
at run (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:210)
```

And also the message below appeared in logs:

```
Application object must be callable.
```

So, I don't understand what is wronh, because this version deployed well before.

**App.yaml:**

```
runtime: python37
service: service_name
instance_class: B2

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app.server

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Comment: Workaround: I don't know why but it works on the flexible environment with the same settings

Comment: From deleted answer: "App Engine is ignoring your custom entrypoint. This is a known issue that's currently being addressed, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131210363." It looks like the issue has been fixed (I don;t know if you will need to redeploy).

Comment: @snakecharmerb, oh thank you. I found a workaround yesterday - it was working with flex environment, so I think yes - I faced with the issue you showed. 
Today I've checked and its really working with the standard environment.

Comment: The credit belongs to [Dustin Ingram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328036/dustin-ingram) - I'm not sure why their answer was not converted to a comment rather than just being deleted.